# Использование слова "пленэр". Примеры

Tags: словоприменение

**Пленэр** — живописная техника изображения объектов при естественном свете в естественных условиях.

Какой диапазон использования у этого слова (действие, создание картины в этой технике; сама техника; картина, изображённая   этой технике)?

**Например:**

> 1. Мы берем одну, заметь - одну чувиху и едем на пленэр. *С.Довлатов "Заповедник"* (выезд к изображаемому объекту и его рисование).

Не подтверждённые примеры:

2. Этот пленэр (картина) получился особенно выразительно.
3. Благодаря отработке пленэра (техники) в студенческие годы он добился значительных успехов в живописи в целом.

Comment: http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CF%EB%E5%ED%FD%F0

Comment: "Мы берем одну, заметь - одну чувиху и едем на пленэр." С.Довлатов "Заповедник"

Comment: думаю способы употребления будут такими же, как и у других жанров изобразительного искусства. в которых я не разбираюсь, поэтому примеров привести не могу.

Answer (score 6):

Корпус русского языка находит 29 текстов со словом "пленэр".

Из них в одном тексте некий "пленэр-мемориал" (текст Пелевина), и ещё в 4 имя собственное.  Из 24 релевантных текстов

- в 16 - рисование на открытом воздухе (`поехал на пленэр`, `он на пленэре` и т. п.)
- в 7 - другое мероприятие на открытом воздухе (пикник, спектакль и т. д.) или просто пребывание на открытом воздухе
- В одном тексте 1916 года точный смысл трудно понять:

`На снегу писать — все иное получается. Вон пишут на снегу силуэтами... А на снегу все пропитано светом. Все в рефлексах лиловых и розовых. Вон как одежда боярыни Морозовой, верхняя, черная, и рубахи в толпе. Все пленэр. Я с 1878 го­да уже пленэристом стал. «Стрельцов» тоже на воздухе писал. Все с натуры писал: и сани, и дровни.`

(В любом случае, текст столетней давности вряд ли актуален.)

Ни в одном случае (кроме, может быть, последнего) пленэр не означает ни картину, ни технику.

Для полноты следует искать слово пленэр во всех падежах и в обоих числах, предоставляю это автору вопроса.

Comment: В последнем примере, насколько я понимаю, художник рассуждает об особенностях освещения на открытом воздухе зимой (на снегу) и пытается объяснить, что из-за такого необычного освещения писать зимние картины лучше с натуры, на открытом воздухе (пленэре), иначе не получится реалистично передать освещение, все будет выглядеть совсем по-другому. Слово "пленэр" имеет значение "рисование на открытом воздухе" (в смысле, что благодаря этому так хорошо получилась картина с боярыней Морозовой, которую он приводит в качестве примера).

Comment: @Lara Да, похоже на то.

Comment: если всех этот ответ устраивает, я думаю отдать этому ответу награду.